# Meaning of Normal Vector in Surface Integration

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, intuition

Is there a good interpretation of what the normal vector (and its magnitude) $$\mathbf{N}=\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial s}\times\frac{\partial\mathbf{X}}{\partial t}$$ to the parametric surface $\mathbf{X}(s,t)$ represents?

In line integrals the quantity $||\mathbf{x}'(t)||$ is the speed of the curve, and the way to "normalize" things is to use the arc-length parameterization.

So does there always exist (for the usual "nice" surfaces) a similar parameterization where $||\mathbf{N}||=1$? Perhaps more stringently, does there always exist a parameterization where $$\left|\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial s}\right|\right|=\left|\left|\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial t}\right|\right|=1\;\;\text{and}\;\;\frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial s}\cdot \frac{\partial \mathbf{X}}{\partial t}=0$$ and if so, what would this mean? Is this some kind of "orthogonal unit speed" parameterization or something? Cheers!

Comment: You can always get $\| \mathbf{N} \| = 1$ through $$\| \mathbf{N} \| = \frac{\partial_t \mathbf{X} \times \partial_t \mathbf{X}}{\| \partial_s \mathbf{X} \times \partial_t \mathbf{X} \| }.$$

Comment: *In line integrals the quantity ||x′(t)|| is the speed of the curve, and the way to "normalize" things is to use the arc-length parameterization.* Can you elaborate on "things"?

Comment: @Nameless For example, scalar line integrals become just $\int_C{f(\mathbf{x}(t))\;\mathrm{d}t}$ without the "adjustment factor" $||f(\mathbf{x})||$. In general the derivative is the unit tangent vector, which is the "normalized" velocity.

Comment: *Is there a good interpretation of what the normal vector (and its magnitude)  to the parametric surface?* We can identify whether the surface is orientable through its normal vector; and as far as I know, we are more concerned with finding the **unit** normal than just the regular normal.

Comment: @OP (your name keeps disappearing) sorry I am still not understanding you. You still haven't told me what the "thing" is.

Comment: @Nameless The 'thing' that is normalized is the velocity vector/derivative $x'$. I am wondering if one can parameterize surfaces so that their tangents are of unit length and perpendicular to one another.

Comment: You can always choose "orthogonal coordinates" (or isothermal coordinates) to parametrize your surface, but there is no canonical choice for parametrizing a surface such as the case for curves.  In fact, the lack of a canonical parametrization serves to make the study of surfaces considerably more difficult than the study of curves.

Comment: @THW Could you elaborate please (perhaps as answer)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction is obvious ($\bf N$ is orthogonal to the tangent plane), but the magnitude is definitely nontrivial: is the local factor of measure change of the parametrization. Is like $\|x'(t)\|$ in curves and abs(jacobian) in the change of variables formula.

EDIT:

The easier case in the change of variables formula is: $A\subset\Bbb R^n$ open, $T:\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^n$ linear, $m=$Lebesgue measure.
$$|\det T|\,m(A)=\int_A|\det T|=\int_{TA}1=m(TA),$$
i.e.,
$$|\det T|={m(TA)\over m(A)}.$$

Comment: Could you elaborate on what that means? I'm not sure what "measure change of the parameterization" is, could you perhaps be more detailed please?

Comment: Start thinking what says the change of variables formula when the integrand is 1.

Comment: I am perfectly familiar with the Jacobian, but I am sorry I really don't see what you're getting at. Could you please be more explicit, maybe add an edit to your answer?

Comment: See the edit and my answer in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627926/understanding-integration-techniques.

Comment: I am really sorry for all these questions - you are taking $T:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ but I am interested in $T:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^3$ so I don't think taking the determinant works.... out of curiosity, would the formula $\sqrt{\det (A^T A)}$ work in general as the "Jacobian" for integrals of functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$?? (Where $A$ would be the derivative matrix of the parameterization of the space over which integration was happening) - and I haven't learned what Lebesgue measures are yet.

Comment: Lebesgue measure is simply length/area/volume... technical details are unimportant. About the dimensions: a parametrized curve is a function $c:[a,b]\longrightarrow\Bbb R^3$, but the *image set* (excluding the usual suspects) is much smaller: a *1D subset* of $\Bbb R^3$. The length is $\int_a^b\|c'(t)\|$dt; think what says this formula in an small interval $[t_0,t_0+\epsilon]$. I will think in your generalized "jacobian".

Comment: Ok, so direction is normal to surface, and magnitude is the amount of "area distortion" that a small rectangle $[s_0,s_0+\epsilon]\times [t_0,t_0+\epsilon]$ receives under the transformation $\mathbf{X}(s,t)$. Does that look right? And thank you very much for your help, cheers!

Comment: You sound doubtful :) Why the .......? Is that wrong?

Comment: Isn't doubt. A comment requires 15 characters of more.

Comment: I see........ :)

Comment: Oh and I forgot to ask, can one always "normalize" by re-parameterizing the surface? What is the answer to the second part of my question?

Comment: Yes, is possible re-parametrize with the condition $\|{\bf N}\|=1$, but I haven't find a reference. About the othogonatily condition I do not know if it will be possible.

Answer (score 1):

Given a parametric representation $(s,t)\mapsto{\bf x}(s,t)$ of a surface $S\subset{\mathbb R}^3$ one usually reserves the letter ${\bf n}$ for the *normalized* surface normal vector:
$${\bf n}(s,t):={{\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_t\over|{\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_s|}\ .$$
The vector product ${\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_t$ itself, resp., the $2$-form
$$d\omega\!\!\!\!\!\omega:={\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_t\ {\rm d}(s,t)\ ,$$
plays a rôle in the computation of *flow integrals*. When the surface $S$ is embedded in a flow field ${\bf v}$ defined in ${\mathbb R}^3$ then
$${\bf v}\cdot d\omega\!\!\!\!\!\omega={\bf v}\cdot ({\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_t)\ {\rm d}(s,t)=\bigl[{\bf v},{\bf x}_s,{\bf x}_t\bigr]\ {\rm d}(s,t)$$
can be interpreted as the amount of fluid traversing the "surface element" $\>dS\>$  spanned by ${\bf x}_s\>ds$ and ${\bf x}_t\>dt$ (an infinitesimal parallelogram) per second, and the flow integral
$$\int_S{\bf v}\cdot d\omega\!\!\!\!\!\omega=\int_S{\bf v}\cdot ({\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_t)\ {\rm d}(s,t)$$
is the total amount of fluid crossing $S$ per second. Note that this integral is free of any square roots.

A parametrization $(s,t)\mapsto{\bf x}(s,t)$ with $|{\bf x}_s\times{\bf x}_s|\equiv1$ is *area preserving*, i.e., pieces $B$ of the $(s,t)$-parameter domain are mapped to pieces of $S$ having the same area as $B$. When $S$ is a rotational surface this can be realized in a rotationally symmetric way; whereas for an "arbitrary" $S$ nothing nice comes out of such an endeavor.

Comment: So can a surface always be re-parameterized as described in the post? See the second part of my question.