# Is there a geometric intuition for integration by parts?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry, intuition

Is there a geometric intuition for integration by parts?

$$\int f(x)g'(x)\,dx = f(x)g(x) - \int g(x)f'(x)\,dx$$

This can, of course, be shown algebraically by product rule, but still where is geometric intuition? I have seen geometry of IBP using parametric equations but I don't get it.

Newest edit: few similar questions has been asked before, but they use parametric equations to show geometry behind IBP. I am interested if there is geometric intuition which uses functions in Cartesian plane or some other, maybe more natural, explanation.

Comment: https://srabbani.com/integration_parts.pdf

Comment: [Related question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/627926/understanding-integration-techniques).

Comment: Another related question: [What is integration by parts, really?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827576/what-is-integration-by-parts-really) (The highest voted answer is in essence what you are looking for)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is integration by parts, really?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/827576/what-is-integration-by-parts-really)

Comment: @glS, not completely. Answer is just a picture without some real explanation

Comment: As you are aware, integration by parts is essentially just the product rule run backwards. There are easy geometric intuitions for the product rule. In some sense, any such thing is ispo facto a geometric intuition for integration by parts.

Comment: @YuiToCheng You can also link directly to the answer, [like this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/827604/152299). You can use the 'share' link just below the answer to fetch its URL.

Comment: @CiaPan Thanks for your reminder. But I don't want everyone to focus on that answer alone since there are other well-written answers to that question.

Answer (score 38):

*Note.* Edited because Adayah pointed out (correctly, and to my chagrin) that this answer was totally sloppy—sloppier even than I intended it to be.  Let's hope it's better now.

---

When we use integration by parts on an integral

$$
\int u(x) \, \mathrm{d}v(x) = \int u(x) v'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

we implicitly treat $u$ and $v$ as parametric functions of $x$.  If we plot these functions against each other on the $u$-$v$ plane, we might obtain something like the below:

[image]

(Note that $v$ is on the horizontal axis, and $u$ on the vertical.)  In this diagram, the purple region below the curve represents the definite integral

$$
\int_{v(x)=2}^3 u(x) \, \mathrm{d}v(x)
    = \int_{x=v^{-1}(2)}^{v^{-1}(3)} u(x) v'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Similarly, the blue region to the left of the curve represents the definite integral

$$
\int_{u(x)=1}^2 v(x) \, \mathrm{d}u(x)
    = \int_{x=u^{-1}(1)}^{u^{-1}(2)} v(x) u'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

Note that we can set

- $x_1$ such that $u(x_1) = 1$ and $v(x_1) = 2$
- $x_2$ such that $u(x_2) = 2$ and $v(x_2) = 3$

and so we can relate those two integrals by

$$
\int_{x=x_1}^{x_2} u(x) v'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
    = \left. u(x) v(x) \phantom\int\!\!\!\!\! \right]_{x=x_1}^{x_2}
    - \int_{x=x_1}^{x^2} v(x) u'(x) \, \mathrm{d}x
$$

---

Obviously this simple visualization of integration by parts relies (at least to some degree) on $u(x)$ and $v(x)$ being one-to-one; otherwise, we have to use signed areas.  However, the necessary rigor can be added.  I'm making the assumption that rigor was not what was needed here.  (ETA: Though more than I provided at first!)

Comment: A sketch of how we address cases where it's not one-to-one: split the integration range at turning points, then handle each such range separately, multiplying $v$ by $-1$ on some if necessary to ensure it's increasing; this doesn't change whether $\int_a^buv^\prime dx=[uv]_a^b-\int_a^bvu^\prime dx$.

Comment: That prompts a question then: let $g(x)=x$, explain the identity $$\int_a^b xf'(x) dx = \int_{f(a)}^{f(b)} f^{-1}(y) dy$$

Comment: @BrianTung I appreciate your professional response. After the correction I think this is a great answer which I can whole-heartedly upvote.

Comment: This is interesting. In the limit, the diagram just illustrates the chain rule, but working with integrals instead allows it to be exact without any infinitesimals.

Comment: Hope this isn't too stupid, but why's there a dx just below the integral sign? Does it mean something? And that's $v(x_1)=3$, right?

Comment: Sorry, meant $v(x_2)=3$ instead of what I wrote earlier.

Comment: @harry: Oh yes, that's correct, I did mean $v(x_2) = 3$; thanks for the nice catch. As for the $dx$ below the integral sign, I don't see what you're referring to. Where is this?

Answer (score 9):

In light of @Adayah's observations, I'll offer a different geometric intuition for $fdg=d(fg)-gdf$, which integrates to the desired result. Consider the special case $f,\,g,\,df,\,dg>0$, so we can draw an $f\times g$ rectangle inside an $(f+df)\times (g+dg)$ rectangle. Apart from a negligible $df\times dg$ corner piece, the trimming $d(fg)$ outside the slightly smaller rectangle is two rectangles of areas $fdg,\,gdf$.

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for. This is nice intuition for the product rule, so can you tranform this into IBP?

Comment: @1b3b As I said, IBP is just the product rule integrated.